# How do get script content using cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cheerio

I am using the cheerio lib and am trying to get this script field - `script type="application/json"`
But for some reason it can not find these script tags. What is wrong? How do I fix?

```
var $ = require('cheerio')
var parsedHTML = $.load(html)
console.log( parsedHTML('script').get().length ); // this is 0
```

Comment: We must guess what you've done wrong?

Comment: I add some code. It's not finding an script tags. Does cheerio not support script?

Comment: That exact code, copied and pasted, using a text string that has the line `<script type="application/json"></script>` in it?  Returns `1` for me.

Answer (score 38):

If you use

```
var parsedHTML = $.load('<html><head><script type="application/json" src="http://myscript.org/somescript.ks"></script></head></html>')
console.log( parsedHTML('script').get()[0].attribs['src'] );
```

You can fetch a url and then use the request to fetch the contents

If you want to get at an inline script, you can do this:

```
console.log( parsedHTML('script').get()[0].children[0].data );
```

Comment: The second option here seems to fail when a `<=` operator is encountered

Answer (score 5):

To those still wandering into this thread, the following solution worked for me:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(html, {xmlMode: false});
$('script').length; // no longer 0
```

(See [htmlparser2's options](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2/wiki/Parser-options))

Comment: Even though it seems to be correct answer according to documentation, it didn't work for me 
I am using `cheerio@1.0.0-rc.10`

Comment: Oddly, doing the opposite (setting `xmlMode` to `true`) worked for me.